# Christmassy movie about a rat in a toy store

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation

I suddenly remembered seeing a movie on T.V. when I was a kid. I have no idea what the story was about, but I remember the following things:

- was animated in a very distinct non-Disney style (unlike anything else either, I recall shakily drawn characters)
- main villain was a rat
- a major scene took place around toys, maybe in a toy store
- it was kind of Christmas/holiday themed or maybe just took place in the winter season.

I remember that it was very strange, but I really liked it. I will know it if I see a picture of it for sure. I have looked through [Wikipedia's list of fictional rodents page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_mice_and_rats) but couldn't find what I was looking for there either.

If anyone can help, and further more, knows if it's available on DVD that would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The Mouse and His Child](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076416/) is the one you're thinking of, I believe. I found it on YouTube. It ran on HBO in the early eighties I think. I watched it several times as a kid. I loved it but at the same time found it to be a little disturbing.

Related:

- [The Mouse and His Child](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076416/) on IMDB
- [The Mouse and His Child](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mouse_and_His_Child_(film)) on Wikipedia

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like [The Great Mouse Detective](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091149/) (1986). The villain was a rat (the appropriately named Professor Ratigan), the mystery concerned a kidnapped toymaker, and although it was in fact produced by Disney, it was during a period when the house style was quite different.

Comment: Nope, that one is Disney. The one I am thinking of was drawn in a very rough style and definitively not Disney. Plus I've seen the Great Mouse detective. But thanks anyway.